# Firefox addon/extension to add a viewport (or other) tag

Tags: android, responsive-design, firefox-addon

I have a style (CSS) for one website and I can add it with Stylish. The problem is the site doesn't have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

So how can I add this tag with some Firefox for Android addon?

Answer (score 2):

To answer my question :-). You can do it and you need 3 things:

1. Greasmonkey equivalent for Android - you can use an [USI addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/userunified-script-injector/).
2. The script to add the tag.
3. `@run-at document-start` user script directive for your script.

Actually the 3rd part is crucial for Firefox, because changing `viewport` meta tag dynamically doesn't work well. Adding it when the document is loaded will give you weird results (see also [PPK's post](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2011/06/dynamically_cha.html)).

So this is a user script example which add the viewport:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Mobile example.com
// @namespace   com.something.unique.to.me
// @description Forces the website to behave responsive. Note that you probably need some CSS too.
// @include     http://example.com/*
// @include     https://example.com/*
// @version     1.0
// @grant       none
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

function addViewport() {
    var metaTag=document.createElement('meta');
    metaTag.name = "viewport"
    metaTag.content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
    document.querySelector('head').appendChild(metaTag);
}

addViewport();
```

Comment: Note, USI addon is a bit hard to use and I stopped using it. You should use Tampermonkey instead which works both on mobile and desktop Firefox.
https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/tampermonkey/